# Finding clusters of numbers in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've searched for this question, but maybe I've been searching for the wrong words, so I added my own:

I wish to read numbers from a file, and find out if there are X amount of numbers within a given range. To give an example:

Imagine a text file with the following numbers:

```
1
2
3
4
8
10
20
22
30
40
```

If there are 4 or more matches on the scale of 1-10, I want to print them out. If there are less than 4 matches on the scale of, say 21-30, it shouldn't print it.

> So the expected output should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 8 and 10, but not the
>   others.

I typed in my own code:

```
file = "text.txt"
count = 0

with open(file, 'r') as file:
        for number in file:
            if 0 <= int(number) <= 10:
                print(number)
                count += 1
if count >= 4:
    print("Found numbers: " + str(count))
```

This works the way I want it to, but only if the file I read has less than 10 numbers. I could of course expand it with several "Count2" "Count3" and so forth, but I would like it to be able to read through a file of any length.
I'm struggling to find a good solution to the issue of how to do it with more than 100 numbers, as I would have to write a lot of if-statements in that case. I will see if I can't find the answer and post it here if no-one else does. :)

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. What is the problem with large files? Do you want all ranges simultaneously?

Comment: Maybe loading the numbers into a list, then based on the length of the list and the value of list[-1] to create a for loop that creates your counters for you. Then iterate through the list comparing values and increasing the necessary counters.

Comment: How do you define a "range"? What is special about 1-10 and 21-30? Why not 10-30 or 4-40? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: What exactly do you want to print when there are 4 or more matches in a given range? What's a "cluster"? How many ranges do you want to check? What defines these ranges and how many of them there are?

Comment: The range should vary, based on the file size. One file could be just 10 numbers, but one could be 40, one could be 8000. The clusters would be "X amount in Y range", so I define the amount of matches within the set interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)? :

```
from itertools import groupby

def load_numbers(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as h:
        for line in h:
            yield int(line)

def group_numbers(numbers):
    return groupby(numbers, key=lambda n: (n-1)//10)

groups = group_numbers(load_numbers('text.txt'))
for _, elements in groups:
    elements = list(elements)
    if len(elements) >= 4:
        print(elements)
```

Comment: I will try this out and see if it works, it's a little advanced, but I will try to see if I understand it once I use it. Thank you :)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, it prints out what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

How about a list comprehension?

Trim the numbers you don't want:

```
minimum = 0
maximum = 10
trimmed = [x for num in file if minimum <= x <= maximum]

if len(trimmed) >= 4:
   print(trimmed)
```

Comment: I would have to run this a lot of times if the numbers in the file exceeded 1000 or something. This might work, and I'll try to use it, but I don't think it quite solves it. Thank you :)

Comment: Why would you have to run it multiple times? It iterates over however big your list size is. It requires an extra list for storage, but unless you're working with extremely large datasets it doesn't matter. And it doesn't matter at all if you otherwise don't need to hold the other values in memory.